# How to shrink code with ProGuard that depends on unimplemented interface

Tags: java, proguard

I have a class with lots of methods. Every method performs a loop over a collection of objects and calls a certain method on that object if it implements an interface.

I am trying to make the code in such a way that proguard would remove the methods that use interfaces without any implementing class.

I have tried with using two kinds of loops over the collection, in both cases ProGuard succeeds in removing the code that uses interface without implementation, but leaves an empty loop.

Given my code:

- **Original code**

  ```
  public class EventBus {

      private ArrayList<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<Handler>();

      public void notifyHappy() {
          for (Handler handler: handlers) {
              if (handler instanceof HandlerHappy) {
                  ((HandlerHappy) handler).notifyHappy();
              }
          }
      }

      public void notifySad() {
          final int size = handlers.size();
          for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
              Handler handler = handlers.get(i);
              if (handler instanceof HandlerSad) {
                  ((HandlerSad) handler).notifySad();
              }
          }
      }

  }
  ```
- **Optimized code**

  ```
  public final class a {
      private ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

      public final void a() {
          Iterator localIterator = this.a.iterator();
          while (localIterator.hasNext())
              localIterator.next();
      }

      public final void b() {
          int i = this.a.size();
          for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
              ;
      }
  }
  ```
- **proguard.cfg**

  ```
  -assumenosideeffects class java.util.ArrayList { 
      public *** get(int); 
      public int size();
  }

  # disabled merging to produce clear output, doesn't affect the shrinking
  -optimizations !class/merging/*,!method/inlining/*
  ```

I want proguard to remove `notifyHappy` method if there is no class implementing `HandlerHappy` interface and to remove `notifySad` method when no class implements `HandlerSad`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect the unimplemented interface to be implemented by a party external to your package ?

If not, then why is the unimplemented interface even there ?
If yes, what is the point of anybody doing so if you let PG "optimize" away the invocations of that method ?

Comment: I do expect 3rd part to implement interfaces, but also the 3rd party will run the proguard. I want to keep the resulting code as minimum and optimal as possible. The 3rd part will implement only some of the interfaces.